# How to resolve variable names which are defined on user variables in jmeter test

Tags: jmeter

I have defined some variables v1 = "somevalue", v2 = "somevalue" in test plan window of jmeter. Now in thread group i use "user defined variables" file and create variable v3 = ${v1}/${v2}.csv

And using this v3 in http request.

here v3 value is not getting resolved. How to fix that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your issue (at least using [JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5), however the functionality used to work for at least 3 previous versions)

1. [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan)

   [image]
2. [User Defined Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables)

   [image]
3. [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) called `${v3}` for demo purposes visualised using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener

   [image]

So please double check your syntax and go for approach in point 3 - this way you will be able to see all defined [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) along with their values.

Comment: If i am giving value to v2 from csv file using csv data set configure, this is not working. you know how to fix it

Comment: You will not be able to use the value from CSV Data Set Config in User Defined Variables  as User Defined Variables are executed **before** anything else. Consider switching from CSV Data Set Config to [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) or [__StringFromFile()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) function. Check out [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) to learn more about JMeter Functions concept.

Comment: Thank you Dmitri for clarification, The approach of __CSVRead() is working.